# I want to remove my array list

Tags: knockout-2.0

my array list is below:

```
this.array_of_name = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'All Ways' },
    { name: 'Brand Cars' },
    { name: 'Carrom' },
    { name: 'Ginger' },
    { name: 'Honey' },
    { name: 'Jar Jar' },
    { name: 'Bert' },
    { name: 'Kitjar' },
    { name: 'Denise' },
    { name: 'Numeric' },
    { name: 'Length' },
    { name: 'Orange' },
    { name: 'Panasonic' },
    { name: 'Rabbit' },
    { name: 'Tarzan' },
    { name: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Yield' },
    { name: 'Zen' }
    ]);
```

i want to remove all items from it using javascript or knockout.

And also want to add search functionality using javascript or knockout.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = [];
var a=["a","b","c"];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
if(a[i]!=="a") newArray.push(a[i]);
```

Or another approach

```
removeAll = function(ary, elem) {
return ary.filter(function(e) { return e != elem });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make empty, just assign empty array to your variable.
ex: this.array_of_name = ko.observableArray([]);